# HTML Form into Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm reasonably new to Javascript so sorry if this has a simple answer.

I would like to make the name that a user inputs in a form into a javascript variable. For example, If the user inputs the name 'James' into the form, I would like the variable 'ans1' to be equal to the string 'James'. Heres my code...

```html
<form>
  Name:
  <input type="text" id="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="makeans1()" />
</form>

<script>
  function makeans1() {
    var ans1 = document.getElementById.value('username');
    alert(ans1);
  }
</script>
```

The reason I have added an alert is to check to see if the code has worked. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this website is not always fit for beginners - They should learn the basics first and only then they should ask on SO, otherwise they'll find themselves ending up with a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Use google, and debug your code, not every question is qualified to be asked on SO

Comment: The whole reason I asked on this website is because i've spent hours looking on google and youtube and trying different ways to get this to work. In case you didn't notice i was very close to getting it right, i just needed one final piece of help which SOME people were happy to give me. Guess I won't be asking any questions anymore. Sorry for wasting your precious time

Comment: It's not about wasting my or anyone else's time, it's about reading about [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and then you could see that this is atcutally a **method** (Not a property) that returns an element based on the id you're passing, The information is there, and you just need to search for it

Comment: And sorry about my first reaction, I removed that comment

Comment: No worries. I also take my first reaction back. I just don't appreciate people calling my questions stupid when I even stated that I'm a beginner in my question. However i understand what you're saying and get that I should have done more research before asking. Maybe try and act more welcoming to inexperienced users of the site as I haven't had the nicest overall experience

Comment: @AlonEitan Wasn't your first SO question https://stackoverflow.com/q/7150321/2886891 also quite basic? For an average SQL programmer it was! :) Just a simple SQL join... Well, I like your first question! However, I think that we should be more patient with the beginners.

Answer (score 1):

**Change**: `var ans1 = document.getElementById.value('username');`.

**To**: `var ans1 = document.getElementById("username").value;`.

```js
function makeans1() {
    var ans1 = document.getElementById("username").value;
    alert(ans1);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Name:
  <input type="text" id="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="makeans1()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct code should be:

```
var ans1 = document.getElementById('username').value;
```

And always put your alert() 's at the beginning of the function. if you want to test function-hit :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace below line

```
var ans1 = document.getElementById.value('username');
```

with

```
var ans1 = document.getElementById('username').value
```